# Question ban:Edited all questions and have two questions that is still in the -

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I have edited all my questions and only two are still negative. I have edited several times. Now what? My "removed" question was removed my my profile by a mod (I requested that). But what should I do about my question that is still negative. I have edited many times and that one question is holding me down. What do you want me to do StackOverflow?

This is not a dupe as far as I know. I have followed all the advice in the links provided.

[When trying to remove an item from array errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925327/when-trying-to-remove-an-item-from-array-errors)

[Scaleing apps in processing and keep the aspect ratio the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572446/scaleing-apps-in-processing-and-keep-the-aspect-ratio-the-same)

Comment: I'm sure you have more negatively received questions that were deleted. The scores of your non-deleted questions sum up to -1 - that shouldn't be enough to get you banned from asking.

Comment: the whole `EDIT` section of the second one is irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @dorukayhan I had more but I edited them to get the positive

Comment: Wait... have you tried posting a new Q recently? As doru says.... your track record should NOT be stopping you here. Do you know if you still are banned?

Comment: @Patrice still banned

Comment: A lot of them were way negative before I edited

Comment: `Bonus as it doesn't need another question: How do I prevent rotation of the screen` is still irrelevant to your question.

Comment: The reason that question was closed in the first place was because you didn't provide any attempts at solving the problem (whether that's a valid reason for said close reason is another matter.)

Comment: I understand. @KevinB. I have no hard feelings and felt that it has done me good. Since then I have almost reached 500 rep on Sci-Fi/Fantasy SE. Now I am ready to work on getting my ban gone. I just don't want to become inactive as a banned person and become another stat.

Comment: Fortunately for you, auto bans aren't permanent. Once you do all you can, the only option left is to wait out the ban. Note however that the first question you ask after the ban better be a good one, if it isn't positively received you'll go right back into the ban.

Comment: Yeah that worries me. I may ask the general chat on SO for advice on my question before I post.

Comment: @KevinB The ban doesn't *end*, you're simply allowed to ask a quesiton despite still meeting the criteria for the ban.  You aren't *re-banned* if the question is bad, rather, you *stay* banned unless the question is *so good* that it is able to single handedly pull you out of your ban.

Comment: You seem to think that editing questions will give you upvotes, or automatically unban you.  It doesn't.  *Fixing the actual problems with your questions that caused them to be poorly received* is what you need to actually do.  Making edits that don't actually turn you posts into great questions doesn't help at all, and in fact likely hurts you.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart I'd be careful posting here regarding things like this and/or making pointless edits to your questions. You may find a few more DVs occurring. It's good that you want to improve but there is a lot of information in the help centre which should clarify what is expected.

Comment: If you notice on my answer (that I removed) I said the words "hopefully" I do not believe that edits = upvotes.

Comment: @Bugs yeah I know that. But if they need downvotes then they get them. I edit and try to fix it again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of these questions has a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

The first has a dump of code and a line that says that somewhere within there you get "Object does not support method splice"

- Calling what function with which arguments?
- What line does the error occur on?
- what does remove a bullet from an array mean? What does that statement mean in terms of the code dump.
- is all the code in the code dump really required to recreate this issue? Is there any code not present that would be required to recreate the issue

The second question has a small amount of pseudo code. We can't run that, so we can't use it to recreate the problem. You claim that image with some arguments distorts the image

- what image is that?
- what does it look like if it's distorted? Screenshots would help.
- is is distorted without scaling?
- where's your testcase we can compile and run so that answerers can test any suggestions we might make?
- at the end you ask a completely unrelated additional question about disabling rotation.

So help us to help you, if you don't you'll just get more downvotes because you're wasting our time asking us to read a question which cannot be answered.

The fact that your questions are currently closed because they *must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* should really have told you all this already. Stop waiting, start editing and fixing.

Comment: I have edited both to have MVCE and my 2nd one has images now. I also removed the other question (the extra)